# Laravel Multi Database based on URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am developing an app that will have a global database and 1 specific database for the client, but this specific database will be loaded according to the url.

**example:**

> if you enter in database1.app.com will automatically get the .ENV with database1 connections and global database, but if you enter in database2.app.com will load database2 and global.

This way i can safe the data for each client.

I have already search about multi tenant, i think this is one of the solutions, but i don't know how can i load the database based on url.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 5.x, you could modify your database.php to change the default DB based on the URL using an inline if statement.

```
'default' => ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'database1.app.com' ? 'database1' : 'database2')),
```